# Помогите исправить дрожание шарика

Tags: python, pygame

Нужно справить шарик который ДРОЖИТ по оси X, в независимости от радиуса. Чем больше я увеличиваю fps тем быстрее шарик падает

````
import random as rnd

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1200, 800

fps = 60

# ship
ship_w = 125
ship_h = 35
ship_speed = 15
ship = pygame.Rect(WIDTH // 2 - ship_w // 2, HEIGHT - ship_h - 10, ship_w, ship_h)
# ball
ball_radius = 10
ball_speed = 6
ball_rect = int(ball_radius * 2 ** 0.5)
print(rnd.randint(ball_rect, WIDTH - ball_rect))
dx, dy = 1, -1
ball = pygame.Rect(rnd.randint(ball_rect, WIDTH - ball_rect), HEIGHT // 2, ball_rect, ball_rect)
pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# image
img = pygame.image.load('SPACE228.jpg').convert()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    sc.blit(img,(0, 0))
    # то что нарисованно (корабль)
    pygame.draw.rect(sc, pygame.Color('purple'), ship)
    pygame.draw.circle(sc, pygame.Color('green'), ball.center, ball_radius)
    # передвижение ball'a
    ball.x += ball_speed * dx
    ball.y += ball_speed * dy
    if ball.centerx < ball_radius or ball.centerx < WIDTH - ball_radius:
        dx = -dx
    if ball.centery < ball_radius:
        dy = -dy
    if ball.colliderect(ship) and dy > 0:
        dy = -dy

    # управление
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and ship.left > 0:
        ship.left -= ship_speed
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and ship.right < WIDTH:
        ship.right += ship_speed
    # screen update
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите, вся ошибка в этих 4 строках,

```py
if ball.centerx < ball_radius or ball.centerx < WIDTH - ball_radius:
    dx = -dx
if ball.centery < ball_radius:
    dy = -dy
```

ball.centerx - это **координаты** центра шарика. А радиус не связян с координатами шарика, а из-за того что шарик постоянно выполняет эти условия он дрожжит (меняет свое направление 1 раз за проход цикла)

Если ты хочешь отталкивание от стенок то напиши:

```py
if ball.right >= WIDTH or ball.left <= 0:
    dx = -dx
if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= HEIGHT:
    dy = -dy
```

Этот код будет работать